# Where Does Firefox Store Cookies on OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox, cookies, macos-sierra

I want to load my Firefox cookies into a `MozillaCookieJar` object for a Python script that I'm writing. What I can't figure out though is where Firefox actually saves its cookies file.
I'm running macOS Sierra (10.12.3) and Firefox 53.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox saves your cookies in a file called "cookies.sqlite", a [SQLlite database](https://www.sqlite.org) in your Firefox [profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).

From "[Finding your profile without opening Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile)":
(OS X 10.7 or above) Click the Finder icon in the dock. On the menu bar, click the Go menu, hold down the option or alt key and select Library. A window will open containing your Library folder.

Open the "Application Support" folder, then open the "Firefox" folder, and then the "Profiles" folder.

Your profile folder is within this folder. If you only have one profile, its folder would have "default" in the name.

For instance:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/########.default/cookies.sqlite
```